# downloading census data from Bhuvan using python

Tags: python

I would like to download census data (year 2001 and 2011) from http://bhuvan5.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage as kml/kmz format for multiple states of India. I am thinking to automate the process using python as the data contains huge number of file.  I am a beginner in this kind of programming. It would be great if any one help me or guide me regarding this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I took a short look at the link you provided. I understand it can get quite complicated for beginners. But I still second @ElvioMartinelli 's comment, that you should tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck, so that we can better help you and you learn more.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly target for a first scrapping project as it has a javascript paginated table.

As you'll need a javascript engine, Python's most friendly option is to use Selenium with python bindings to scrap your page.

Before using it, you should have read some basics on html DOM and xpaths.